# Are the roots exposed on this bur oak sprout?

Tags: oak, sprouting

This bur oak acorn that I planted in the fall has started to sprout over the past few days and I'm wondering if it needs to be buried a little deeper in the soil. It hadn't grown at all in like two months, with just the dark green part sticking out of the acorn shell.  As you can see from the pictures, it is going through a growth spurt.

Bur Oak sprout 1/26/2024
[image: Bur Oak sprout 1/26/2024]

Bur Oak sprout 1/29/2024
[image: Bur Oak sprout 1/29/2024]

I think that brown part coming out of the soil was covered up by the acorn shell until I repotted it about a week ago. I'm not sure if it is stem or root. I haven't found any good reference pictures so I thought I'd ask the good folks on stackexchange for some help. Thank you!

Comment: I think its fine as it is

Comment: Did you disturb the acorn in repotting it? There's a lot of stored energy in the meat of the acorn, if you knock that off when repotting (before it's used up) it's a big setback to the plant.

Comment: It was a pretty frail husk I believe. It had a nice taproot going all the way to the bottom of a one gallon ice cream bucket. Now I'm trying to figure out how it even sprouted since it's been indoors all winter. I put most of them outside but the squirrels ate them.  I have one more in here that is still in the same phase that this one was in last week, just a dark green little bud with the acorn still attached. I wonder if I should put them outside now or maybe in the garage. Would a squirrel eat it at this point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have fond memories of growing burr oaks from acorns and was trying bonsai techniques on them.

- I don't see anything to worry about with the seedling
- they need to overwinter outside and are not indoor plants
- when overwintering don't make the mistake I made and assume that wildlife won't eat them
- it was difficult to get the leaves to reduce in size.  A six inch tall plant with leaves that are two or three inches long is not a good bonsai candidate
- putting the stones on the surface of the soil will keep the soil moister. I recommend removing the stones.  If you add a capillary wick now while plant is young you should be able to get moss to grow which is a lovely look and which my burr oaks tolerated

The brown part of the stem is where the acorn was attached and is not part of the root system. The roots begin below the soil line.  At this stage it is growing a tap root with a few laterals.  There is no need to repot yet, perhaps in the spring.

Comment: Did you mean "not indoor plants?"

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing your expertise with bur oaks! One important detail I want to mention is that the acorns I planted had germinated outdoors in early fall. I found hundreds of them that had sprouted roots under some landscape plastic in my yard. I planted about 20 in ice cream buckets and brought them inside. Afterwards I learned about the outdoor overwintering requirement so I put most of them outside and kept a couple indoors to see what would happen. Squirrels sniped the ones I put outside. This is one that I kept inside all winter. Do you think it has a chance at this point?

Comment: @YoeyYutch  I am sure as long as this plant has a cool period during the next year it should be fine. These are strong seedlings that used to being pruned by wildlife and having a hard time in the undergrowth of the forest for years.  Consider overwintering next year in a cooler that is outdoors.  Cool and animal proof!

Comment: The overwintering is key to sprouting and not as essential later.

Comment: @YosefBaskin it is my understanding that deciduous trees need a cool period yearly, depending on where they were grown

Comment: Yes, they like a cool rest, but unless they need it for fruit or germination, they don't need it. You can simulate the rest with a dry spell.

Comment: I really appreciate your help! This little fella is so cool. He grew like a half inch today. Now 3" tall. His mother lives within five feet of the corner of our garage.  She has a circumference of 100"/254 cm, which means she's at least 150 years old according to internet tree age calculators. This spring I discovered that the root collar was buried two feet underground, of which I was able to excavate about 18". It'll be tricky to do much more due to the proximity to the house and maintaining enough slope for drainage. Uh oh. I'm  almost out of characters. To be continued...

Comment: I know that the garage was built in 1965. Based on the artifacts I found in the dirt during excavation such as pottery, glassware and rusted metal hardware, I think that's when they buried the tree and undoubtedly damaged a portion of the roots. I found a large chicken of the woods mushroom growing right next to it a few years ago, and with oak wilt in the neighborhood, she may not have many years left. Maybe that's why she unleashed the most torrential downpour of acorns I have ever seen (or heard!) this summer.  Ope. Need more characters. To be continued again...

Comment: It really is a testament to how industrious the squirrels are. I have two giant oak trees in my yard, the other one being even bigger and probably over 200 years old. For two centuries they've been raining down acorns and not a single one has grown into a tree. Hopefully I can change that. I was so surprised to find all those acorns with roots sticking out of them that I didn't do a great job planting them. All it takes is one though.  My tree is a tough old gal too. I think she's going unleash the fury again in a couple of years, and when she does, I'll be ready!

Comment: @kevinskio Just to finish up and fully answer the original question, do the roots begin where the stem turns from green to brown? If so, could you please add that to your answer? Then I can mark it as accepted. Thanks again!

Comment: @YoeyYutch and done!

Comment: @kevinskio Thank you. I did repot before I read your update. I put it in a 4" ABS pipe that is about a foot long. I left the brown part above the soil and removed the rocks like you suggested. Seems to be doing well, still leafing out and growing taller. His sibling from the ice cream bucket sprouted up an inch too.  I think he was delayed because I accidentally damaged the roots during the first repotting. Took me by surprise how deep they were. He must have been busy doing repairs.